# React / Laravel (php) SPA на одном (Apache) сервере

Tags: php, apache, laravel, reactjs, spa

Здравствуйте, хочу сделать SPA приложение, на фронте будет react, а на бэке rest full api на laravel. Все это я хочу разместить на одном Apache сервере, на одном домене (myapp.ru/index урлы моего реакт приложения, запросы будут улетать на myapp.ru/api/...). 
Нормальная ли это практика, я так понимаю у меня будет проблема с роутингом, и мне придется делать всегда реврайт на index.html при перезагрузке страницы. Не будет ли у меня проблем с тем, что я буду делать ajax запросы на одном домене с фронта на бэк, как мне настроить сервер что бы он пропускал эти запросы, еще будут ларавельные урлы на админку. 
Объясните пожалуйста что, и как нужно настроить что бы все нормально работало. Или это вообще бредовая идея, и реакт должен работать на node.js сервере, и отдельно laravel на apache. Буду очень благодарен за разъяснения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> я так понимаю у меня будет проблема с роутингом

Нет, не будет.

> нормальная ли это практика

Это обычная практика

> буду делать ajax запросы на одном домене с фронта на бэк

Делайте их через сокеты или через 127.0.0.1 и всё будет в порядке

Ставьте вместе, друг другу эти продукты никак не мешают.
p.s. Но вопрос всё же причешите по форматированию и формулировкам.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, Вы не могли бы подробней объяснить что значит "Делайте их через сокеты или через 127.0.0.1 и всё будет в порядке" или дать ссылку как с реакта делать таки запросы.

Comment: Проблемы с запросами уже есть, при перезагрузке страницы меня бросает на 404. Я сделал редирект на index.html всегда, а как мне быть с админкой, делать исключение в htaccess на урлы админки? Извините за столь много вопросов, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

для простоты отправляйте все get запросы в статическую директорию где лежит ваш клиент на react:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

app.get('*', function (request, response { 
response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))})
```

а уже в react обрабатывайте все get запросы как вам нужно, например с помощью [react-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router)